# Tweaking axis labels and names orientation for 3D plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

I am making this 3D plot using matplotlib:

```
ax.plot_surface(x_surf, y_surf, np.reshape(npp, (max_temp/step, max_temp/step)), linewidth=0.2,cmap=palettable.colorbrewer.sequential.Greens_9.mpl_colormap)
```

How can I make the axis label and axis names look more like this plot:
[image]

Comment: Now I am also interested, the second axes looks way cooler!

Answer (score 6):

As far as I understood, you want change the "axis label" and "axis names".

Unfortunately I could only do part of it (I hope that's something **new** to you and that someone else finds the second part of it):

[image]

[image]

I did some changes in http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/pathpatch3d_demo.html in order to obtain the images above

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, PathPatch
# register Axes3D class with matplotlib by importing Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d as art3d
from matplotlib.text import TextPath
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D

def text3d(ax, xyz, s, zdir="z", size=None, angle=0, usetex=False, **kwargs):

    x, y, z = xyz
    if zdir == "y":
        xy1, z1 = (x, z), y
    elif zdir == "y":
        xy1, z1 = (y, z), x
    else:
        xy1, z1 = (x, y), z

    text_path = TextPath((0, 0), s, size=size, usetex=usetex)
    trans = Affine2D().rotate(angle).translate(xy1[0], xy1[1])

    p1 = PathPatch(trans.transform_path(text_path), **kwargs)
    ax.add_patch(p1)
    art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p1, z=z1, zdir=zdir)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.tick_params(axis='x',direction='out', length=6, width=2, colors='r')

text3d(ax, (4, -2, 0), "X-axis", zdir="z", size=.5, usetex=False,
       ec="none", fc="k")
text3d(ax, (12, 4, 0), "Y-axis", zdir="z", size=.5, usetex=False,
       angle=.5*3.14159, ec="none", fc="k")
text3d(ax, (12, 10, 4), "Z-axis", zdir="y", size=.5, usetex=False,
       angle=.5*3.14159, ec="none", fc="k")

ax.set_xlim3d(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim3d(0, 10)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 10)

plt.show()
```

I was expecting to find how to develop the second part of this problem at http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html, but I did not find it yet.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks @awdk, this is a great start and hopefully someone can complete the 2nd part

Comment: I am not tracking with python, but this seems redundant: `elif zdir == "y":`